# Algorithmic complexity converting CSC to CSR

Tags: algorithm, sparse-matrix, asymptotic-complexity

I was wondering what the algorithmic complexity of a conversion from `CSC (compressed sparse column)` to `CSR (compressed sparse row)` is?

Say I have

- a CSC `m x m`-matrix `A = csc(m,m)` with `n` non-zero elements
- a CSR `m x m`-matrix `B = csr(m,m)` with `n` non-zero elements

Now I do the conversion from `CSC -> CSR` with `B = convert(A)`.

---

How costly and complex is it?
Can anyone guide me through it? Or clarify things? Thanks

Comment: Scipy (**the** basic numerical computation package for python along numpy) docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/sparse.html#usage-information): ```All conversions among the CSR, CSC, and COO formats are efficient, linear-time operations.``` (probably meaning linear-time in NNZ-size)

Answer (score 5):

Following up on @sascha's comment:

> Complexity: Linear.  Specifically O(nnz(A) + max(n_row,n_col))

Taken from the scipy [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/3b36a574dc657d1ca116f6e230be694f3de31afc/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h#L376). It does not matter whether you compute `CSC -> CSR` or `CSR -> CSC` ([see here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/3b36a574dc657d1ca116f6e230be694f3de31afc/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csc.h#L111)).